# How can Monoid r => Const r of the optic Fold type be generalized to Contravariant + Applicative?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Starting from this `Getter` type

```
type Getter s a = forall r. (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r s
```

we need an additional `Monoid` constraint to obtain a `Fold`:

```
type Fold s a = forall r. Monoid r => (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r s
```

But `Fold`'s actual and more general type is

```
type Fold s a = forall f. (Contravariant f, Applicative f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

I understand that `Contravariant` is used to exclude `Identity` and thus ensure that we can only get the value. But I don't understand how `Monoid r` corresponds to `Applicative`? Sure, `Const` is also an Applicative but where is the monoid hidden?

Sorry for this confusing question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Monoid` instance is hidden in the constraint of the `Applicative` instance for `Const r`.

[`Const r` is *only* an instance of `Applicative` if `r` is an instance of `Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Const.html#line-86):

```
instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m) where
   ...
```